# Latest scipy version on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, scipy, apt

Why is the version of scipy that comes from apt-get on ubuntu only 13.3? Scipy is now on version 16! I need `scipy.optimize.linprog`, which was first available in version 15. What's the easiest way to perform the update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just paste it to your terminal

```
sudo pip install --upgrade scipy
```

Comment: It failed the first time because I needed to install gfortran, but ya basically I apt-get removed scipy and then did pip install scipy